# Why can't I set the ReceiveTimeout property on System.Net.Sockets.Socket?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm attempting to set the `ReceiveTimeout` property an a `System.Net.Sockets.Sockets` object. I get no exceptions, but the value doesn't stick. Example:

```
      m_socket = new Socket(RemoteEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

      m_socket.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Milliseconds;
      Debug.WriteLine($"Set ReceiveTimeout to {m_socket.ReceiveTimeout} ms");
```

Output:

```
Set ReceiveTimeout to 0 ms
```

I know there's a lot that goes on under the scenes when I set this property, but if there's a failure, it appears to be silent. Why doesn't the value stick?

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly recommend reflecting on your diagnostic process after reading my answer - the problem isn't with sockets, and a bit of time spent reducing this to an absolutely minimal example would probably have helped you find the answer for yourself.

Comment: You are using TCP which gets ACK for every sent message.  The ACK is handled at the ethernet interface.   There is 3 reties at 5 seconds apart.  So you will not get an error for at least 15 seconds.  Are you using Keep-Alive?  You will not get an error at receive end unless Keep-Alive is enabled.  Keep Alive periodically sends a datagram with zero bytes in message.  Timeout will only occur when the Keep-Alive stops.

Comment: @jdweng: The problem shown has nothing to do with that. The OP doesn't get as far as the receive timeout actually having any effect. The problem is that they're setting the property value to 0. (Everything you've written may be relevant later, but only once they've actually managed to set the property to the value they want.)

Comment: @JonSkeet : You should be a little clearer.  Setting to zero is really setting to infinite.  ReceiveTimeout  will only work if keep alive is on and a Keep-Alive is missed.

Comment: @jdweng: The point is that the OP didn't expect to set it to 0. They expected to set it to 1000 - they've asked the question because they didn't expect the property to have the value 0 after setting it. My answer explains *why* they've actually ended up setting the property to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the value to 0, because that's the value of `TimeSpan.Milliseconds` for a 1-second timespan. The `Milliseconds` property is effectively "the sub-second millisecond component" - in the same way that (for example) the `Minutes` property for `TimeSpan.FromHours(1.5)` is 30, not 90. From the [docs for `TimeSpan.Milliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.milliseconds?view=net-6.0):

> The millisecond component of the current TimeSpan structure. The return value ranges from -999 through 999.

If you want the *total* number of milliseconds in a TimeSpan, use the `TotalMilliseconds` property, then cast to `int`.

Example:

```cs
using System;

var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
Console.WriteLine(timeSpan.Milliseconds); // Prints 0
Console.WriteLine((int) timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds); // Prints 1000
```